# How to add mist to an image programmatically

Tags: python

I am new to blender, and have a script that generates an image programmatically. I would now also like to add some mist to it. To see which properties to change, I tried to adapt from the code used for [this panel](https://pastebin.com/wnDMDuiD). Since I wanted to start simple, I left out the add/multiply nodes, but I think the mist should be able to work without them. I don't really understand the difference between the world's mist settings and the ones added through the composition tab, but I tried adding them both (either one separate has no effect either).

I currently have the following code, yet the image doesn't show any mist.

```
scene = bpy.context.scene
scene.view_layers["ViewLayer"].use_pass_mist = True
scene.use_nodes = True

nodes = scene.node_tree.nodes

mist = bpy.data.worlds[scene.world.name].mist_settings
mist.use_mist = True
mist.intensity = 1
mist.depth = 1
mist.start = 0

viewer_node = nodes.new('CompositorNodeViewer')
render_layer_node = nodes.get('Render Layers')

scene.node_tree.links.new(render_layer_node.outputs["Mist"], viewer_node.inputs["Image"])
```

Could anyone let me know how I am supposed to add mist programmatically? I am using Blender 3.1.2.

Comment: The viewer node does not send the image to the output file. It only shows a preview in the compositor. Are you taking this into account?

Comment: I did not know that. What should I do instead to get mist in my final render?

Comment: I’m not very familiar with mist settings yet, but I do know you need an Output node rather than a Viewer node to have the compositing go into the final image.

Comment: How do you mean that the image was generated programmatically? The mist pass works with the 3D space, so if the images is not a render of something in the 3-D space, mist pass settings will have no reactive effect on it.

Comment: I mean that the whole blender 3d scene is created by code, since it needs to be an automated process (it runs with blender in the background, so I cannot click buttons in the blender app itself). The scene itself (before rendering) does span the 3D space.

Comment: Okay, that’s good. I’ll experiment with some mist settings when I get the chance, that is if you haven’t figured it out already by then (a few hours I expect?). God help you! 

Comment: Thank you so much! I have tried all variations/things I could think of (probably just missing a small setting somewhere due to my inexperience with Blender) but to no avail, really hope you manage to find something!

Comment: EDIT: I have got it to do something by ditching the CompositorNodeViewer and instead connecting both the mist and image output of the render layer to an add, which is then connected to the composite layer. This makes the image misty, but it also makes it grayscale (unwanted). I also feel like it ignores the mist.start and mist.depth settings (I need the amount of mist to be configurable). So curious what you come up with?

Comment: looks like I worked out the answer concurrently with you.  I think I'll leave my answer for anyone who happens to have a similar problem in the future.

Comment: @MartyFouts You also solved the issue with it becoming grayscale and explained it very well, please do leave it:) And thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The mist pass doesn't produce an image; but rather depth data that can be used as a factor input to a mix node that mixes the image with a color based on distance from the camera.  The basic layout is

[image: Simplest use of the mist pass]

So you need to modify your code to add a *Mix* node and make the links shown.

Here's your code modified to do that

```py
scene = bpy.context.scene
scene.view_layers["ViewLayer"].use_pass_mist = True
scene.use_nodes = True

nodes = scene.node_tree.nodes

mist = bpy.data.worlds[scene.world.name].mist_settings
mist.use_mist = True
mist.intensity = 1
mist.depth = 1
mist.start = 0

#viewer_node = nodes.new('CompositorNodeViewer')
compositor_node = nodes.get('Composite')
render_layer_node = nodes.get('Render Layers')
mix_rgb_node = nodes.new('CompositorNodeMixRGB')

scene.node_tree.links.new(render_layer_node.outputs["Image"], mix_rgb_node.inputs["Image"])
scene.node_tree.links.new(render_layer_node.outputs["Mist"], mix_rgb_node.inputs["Fac"])

scene.node_tree.links.new(mix_rgb_node.outputs["Image"], compositor_node.inputs["Image"])
```

NOTE: I have not addressed setting the color of the mist (The second input of the mix shader.)  Also, the mist output is often modified by a color ramp node or a set of math nodes.  I have not shown that either.

As a bonus, you may want to place the new Mix node between the Render Layers and Composite nodes.  This code places the left edge half way between the left edges of the two and also the top.

```py
new_location = (compositor_node.location + render_layer_node.location) / 2
mix_rgb_node.location = new_location
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Shouldn't the penultimate line connect the "Mist" output though instead of the image? Also am I correct in setting the world's mist properties to control the amount/strength of mist and such? Or should I do that differently?

Comment: @Eric Yes.  that's a typo in my code.  good spot. I'll fix it now.